# How to give different colours to element in the same line in bootstrap, laravel blade

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm very new in this and my question might be very stupid, please forgive me.

So I'm working on an e-commerce website that will have multiple sellers displaying their products in one store, there will be a function to display the name of the seller like this "Sold by: Xavier". So what I want to do is let the word "sold by" be in different colour and the seller's name should be in a different colour too.
Take a look at my codes below, it will display "Sold by: Xavier" but in only one colour (black).

```
<span style="color:black;">Sold by: {{$product->seller->username}}</span><br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enclose the seller's name in another span. Like this -

```html
        <span style="color:black;">Sold by: <span style="color:hotpink;"><a href="http://example.com/user/123/">{{$product->seller->username}}</a></span></span><br>
```

Replace http://example.com/user/123/ with the link of your seller.

Comment: This solved it, Thank you. Is there a way to add a link to this {{$product->seller->username}} and make it link to the seller's profile? Thanks for the help

Comment: Added to answer.

Comment: I did it as bellow and it would appear that it has instead inherited a different colour from somewhere else and not the orange colour I specified.                                                                                                                    <span style="color:black;">Sold by: <span style="color:orange;"><a href="{{route('viewprofile',['uniqueid'=>Auth::user()->uniqueid])}}">{{Auth::user()->username}}</a></span></span><br>

Comment: make it as  - style="color:orange !important;"

Answer (score 0):

Your can generate Radom color using this random_color function & put soldby and name different element

```
     <?php
     function random_color(){  
     return sprintf('#%06X', mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF));
     } ?>


<span><span  style="color:<?php echo random_color() ?>">soldby:</span> test1</span>
```